# Strange BTC rate behavior when buying bitcoins

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I have decided to buy some bitcoins using the Bitcoin.com wallet app and I have just received the invoice for my transaction of 1000 EUR to BTC.

The rate of the BTC for the last days is always around 5850 EUR. But in my receipe I see that they have used a rate of 6032 EUR.

I do not understand that gap... Would it be a magic trick in order to get more money on customers ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but two options come to mind:  a)  the "price" of financial assets are the current bid/ask and general average of closed transactions.   You might have been on the high end of the average. You should verify the deal details before purchase/sale.  b) some exchanges charge a premium to the parties, again, know the details before you commit